# Under Review immediately, what does it mean?

Tags: paper-submission

I submitted a paper to a journal. Initially, it showed "New Submission", and changed to "Under Review" after an hour or so. This is not what I have usually observed. I would usually expect something like "Editor Assigned" kind of a thing. What does it mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like)

Comment: Yes, a duplicate, but likely it means that the editor decided to send it out for review and started the process. Don't read too much in to it, other than that it isn't an immediate desk reject.